# Does this code have any malicious scam code?

Tags: solidity, remix, uniswap, scam

I was looking at the code here:
https://rentry.co/mputa/raw

But after looking at the code, if I am not wrong, the coder is transferring tokens from your wallet to his address. Am I wrong? Is it a scam?

Comment: Yes, it is a well known scam contract.

Answer (score 1):

Solely by checking the withdrawal function I think there is 95% to be malicious :)

```
    /*
     * @dev withdrawals profit back to contract creator address
     * @return `profits`.
     */
    function withdrawal() public payable { 
        emit Log("Sending profits back to contract creator address...");
        payable(withdrawalProfits()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
```

You see the `withdrawal` function can be one liner without invoking any other fuctions but this one is calling function after function it is quite hard tracking what really happens there.